# KeePassXC can't open existing database in Ubuntu 21.10. How to fix it?

Tags: keepassxc

KeePassXC 2.7.0 can't open existing database in Ubuntu 21.10.

When I click "[Open existing database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SXnH.png)" or "Import from KeePass 1" or "Help > User Guide" nothing happen.

I can only create new database but I also can't save it.

All [permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p1Bn.png) in Software Center are granted for KeePassXC.

How can I find the reason and fix it?

Comment: how did you install keepassxc?  Is there any type of logs in /var/log/syslog from apparmor or snapd about DENIED when trying to open the files?

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstall the software?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling keepass 2.7.0

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

When it's done type

```
sudo synaptic
```

Search for `keepassxc` and select version 2.6.6. Hit **apply** and it will install the older version that isn't broken.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you stay using **a not supported browser like Thorium**, you must create a file `org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser.json` in:

```
/.config/thorium/NativeMessagingHosts/
```

with this settings

```
{
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://pdffhmdngciaglkoonimfcmckehcpafo/",
        "chrome-extension://oboonakemofpalcgghocfoadofidjkkk/"
    ],
    "description": "KeePassXC integration with native messaging support",
    "name": "org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser",
    "path": "/usr/bin/keepassxc-proxy",
    "type": "stdio"
}
```

Save and restart your browser and try again.

Or try check in `~/.config/YOUR-BROWSER-NAME/NativeMessagingHosts/` and search for `org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser.json` if the folder is empty, simply must create a file and set the data.